# In Evans (section on parabolic equations), why can he assume that $u(x_0, t_0)$ is positive?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, parabolic-pde

In Evan's proof for the Weak maximum principle

[image]

He simply assumes that $u(x_0, t_0) > 0$.

[image]

Why can he make this assumption? I have spent some time on this but unfortunately I don't see it. Does it follow from some result for parabolic equations or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By continuity, $u$ assumes its max on $\bar U_T$. If it is assumed on the parabolic boundary, there is nothing to prove. If it is assumed inside and it is $\le 0$ there is nothing to prove either because the max on the right hand side is $\ge 0$. The only case to be considered is that of a  positive max inside, and that actually never happens, as shown.

Comment: I didn't notice the right hand side had a plus sign, i.e. $u_+$ not simply $u$. Thanks!